# ¿Cómo hacer un IN con MySQL desde Typescript?

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, typescript

Intento buscar unos artículos haciendo una consulta con un IN, pero al hacer el `join` el resultado del array queda 23,45,56,78 sin los corchetes. Pero como queda como un string supongo que por eso no busca. ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer una búsqueda así?

```
let arraybuscar=[23,45,56,78]

let buscar=await this.db.conexion.query('SELECT * FROM articulo a WHERE a.id IN('+arraybuscar.join()+')')

console.log(buscar)

////buscar regresa vacio/////
```

Comment: Usa `join(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método join une los elementos, usando como separador lo que le pases como parámetro. Si no le pasas nada, concatena sin más el resultado de llamar a `.toString()` para cada elemento. Por tanto tienes la opción de pasar la coma como parámetro o llamar al método `toString()` del array, que automáticamente realiza un join usando comas:

```js
let array=[23,45,56,78]


console.log('Usando .join() =>', array.join());
console.log('Usando .join(",") =>', array.join(','));
console.log('Usando .toString() =>', array.toString());

console.log('Query: ', `SELECT * FROM articulo a WHERE a.id IN (${array.toString()})`)
```

Comment: tenia una duda, la forma en como se arma la query evita las inyecciones sql ?